# dcast - error: Aggregate function missing

Tags: r, reshape2, dcast

A little background information regarding my question: I have run a trial with 2 different materials, using 2x2 settings. Each treatment was performed in duplo, resulting in a total number of 2x2x2x2 = 16 runs in my dataset. The dataset has the following headings, in which repetition is either 1 or 2 (as it was performed in duplo).

**| Run | Repetition | Material | Air speed | Class. speed | Parameter of interest |**

I would like to transform this into a dataframe/table which has the following headings, resulting in 8 columns:

**| Run | Material | Air speed | Class. speed | Parameter of interest from repetition 1 | Parameter of interest from repetition 2 |**

This means that each treatment (combination of material, setting 1 and setting 2) is only shown once, and the parameter of interest is shown twice.

I have a dataset which looks as follows:

```
 code     rep material airspeed classifier_speed fine_fraction
1 L17       1 lupine         50             600          1
2 L19       2 lupine         50             600          6
3 L16       1 lupine         60             600          9
4 L22       2 lupine         60             600          12
5 L18       1 lupine         50             1200         4
6 L21       2 lupine         50             1200         6
```

I have melted it as follows:

```
melt1 <- melt(duplo_selection, id.vars = c("material", "airspeed", "classifier_speed", "rep"),
          measure.vars=c("fine_fraction"))
```

and then tried to cast it as follows:

```
cast <- dcast(melt1, material + airspeed + classifier_speed ~ variable, value.var = "value")
```

This gives the following message:

> Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'

and this dataframe, in which the parameter of interest is counted rather than both values being presented.

Comment: (1) Please don't paste data as an *image*, I'm not going to spend time transcribing it, especially when you have it in a convenient textual format on your console. It it much better to include sample data in your question by pasting the output from `dput(x)`, where `x` is the sample (perhaps `head(myframe)`). (2) Is this `data.table::dcast` or `reshape2::dcast`?

Comment: (3) The message about `defaulting to 'length'` is not an error, it is just a *message* telling you that you did not provide an aggregating function. If you read `?dcast` (from whichever package), it mentions `fun.aggregate=`.

Comment: I used reshape2::dcast

My apologies for the picture, I will upload the data as a table in my question

Comment: It can be difficult to produce a good, reproducible question, and taking shortcuts frequently breaks things. In this case, `Error: id variables not found in data: rep`. There's an R package `reprex` that helps with this process, by ensuring that code you intend to post here does not error for (accidental, avoidable) reasons like this.

Comment: We are still in the position that *this is not an error*, nor is it necessarily wrong. It is just informing you that widening/reshaping with `dcast` can result in data aggregation/combination, and you have not been explicit about how you want that done. You've not mentioned if the results from `dcast(.)` are correct; if they are, then that *message* goes away by adding `dcast(., fun.aggregate=length)`. If not, then please [edit] your question and add what you expect the results to be.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your effort and time to try to help me out, after a little puzzling I found out what I had to do.

I added *replicate* to each observation, being either a 1 or a 2, as the trial was performed in duplo.

Via the code

```
cast <- dcast(duplo_selection, material + airspeed + classifier_speed ~ replicate, value.var = "fine_fraction")
```

I came to the 5 x 8 table I was looking for.